# Let $G$ be a finite group of order $6.$ Then, $\exists g,h \in G-\{e\}$ such that $o(g) = 2$ and $o(h)=3.$

Tags: abstract-algebra

May I know if my proof to the a/m claim is correct? Thank you.

Let $G =\{g_1,g_2,g_3,g_4,g_5, e\}.$ By Lagrange theorem, $o(g) = 2 $ or $3, \forall g\in G -\{e\}$

1.) Suppose $o(g)=2, \forall g\in G-\{e\}.$

Note that $g_1g_2 \neq g_2 $ otherwise $g_1 = e.$ Similarly, $g_1g_2 \neq g_1. $

WLOG, let $G'=\{e, g_1,g_2,g_3,g_1g_2\},$ where the elements are pairwise distinct. Indeed, $G = \{g_3g_2\} \bigsqcup G'.$  Clearly, $g_3g_2 \neq g_2, g_3, g_1g_2,e.$ If $g_3g_2 = g_1,$ then $g_3 = g_1g_2.$ (Contradiction)

Now, let $g_1g_3 \in G. $ Clearly, $g_1g_3 \neq e, g_1, g_3, g_1g_2.$
If $g_1g_3 = g_2,$ then $g_1(g_3g_2) =e$ and so $g_3g_2 = g_1$ (Contradiction) If $g_1g_3 = g_3g_2, $ then $g_1g_3g_3g_2 = (g_3g_2)^2 =e$ and so $g_1 = g_2$(Contradiction).

i.e. $\exists g\in G -\{e\} $ such that $o(g)=2.$

2.) Similarly, we can prove $\exists g\in G -\{e\} $ such that $o(g)=2.$

Comment: BTW there aren't a whole lot of non-abelian groups of order 6.

Answer (score 2):

Assume all elements ($\ne 1$) have order $2$. Then $G$ is abelian (this is an early exercise in virtually evrey introductory book on group theory).

Assume all element ($\ne 1$) have order $3$. Then $g\mapsto g^{-1}$ is a fixpoint-free involutory map of $G\setminus\{e\}$ to itself, hence $|G\setminus\{e\}|$ is even.

Answer (score 1):

If for all $x,y\in G-\{e\}$; $|x|=|y|=2$ then $|xy|=2$ and so $xy=(xy)^{-1}$ or $xy=yx$. This means what @Hagen remarked you. Since the group is finite, so $G$ will be isomorphic with the direct sum of some $\mathbb Z_2$. Therefore your group is necessarily  an elementary abelian $2-$group.

Comment: Thank you. I don't quite understand why is $G$ is isomorphic to direct sum of some $\mathbb{Z}_{2}.$ (p.s. I have yet to learn direct sum).

Comment: @AlexyVincenzo: I am sorry that I posted a point out of your knowledge. In fact, we use the Fundamental theorem for finite abelian groups here. When the finite group $G$ is abelian so this theorem helps us to consider it as a direct sum of some $2-$ cyclic groups. Since we assumed that all elements are of order $2$, so it makes the groups to be $\mathbb Z_2$.

Comment: Thank you! But is there other simpler ways(without the use of direct sum or cauchy theorem)?